# Largest subgroup of $SU(n)$ for which the adjoint action preserves specific inner product on $\mathfrak{su}(N)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, oc.optimization-and-control

Given $A,B \in \mathfrak{su}(n)$ such that $K(A, B)=0$, I am looking for the largest subgroup $H$ of $SU(n)$ for which:

$K \left(A, Ad_{U}(B) \right) = 0, \ \ \forall U \in H$ where $K$ is the Killing form. Finding the Lie algebra of $H$ would be desirable.

Comment: Why do you think that there is one largest subgroup?  For example, I imagine that, for the generic pair $A,B\in{\frak{su}}(n)$, there will be two subgroups, $P = \{ U\in\mathrm{SU}(n)\ |\ \mathrm{Ad}_U(A) = A\}$ and  $Q = \{ U\in\mathrm{SU}(n)\ |\ \mathrm{Ad}_U(B) = B\}$ that satisfy your condition and, most likely, they will each be maximal, even though they could be of different dimensions.

Comment: Why do you say most likely they will be maximal? Won't the group of all such $U$ be the largest. By maximal do you mean, one we can't extend to a larger supergroup? Or rather, simply the such largest group. Perhaps I am confused.

Comment: Generally, it won't be true that the set $S_{A,B}$ consisting of all $U\in\mathrm{SU}(n)$ that satisfy $K\bigl(A,\mathrm{Ad}_U(B)\bigr)=0$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(n)$, so the best you can hope for is to look for the 'largest' (i.e., highest dimension) subset $H\subset S_{A,B}$ that forms a subgroup, i.e., is closed under multiplication and inverse.

Comment: How can one see that it's not a group? Do we really mean it's not a group or just not a sub Lie group. Based on this, how do we hope to assign it a dimension, can we know that it's a smooth manifold at least?

Comment: Well, take a simple example:  Let $n=2$ and let $A$ and $B$ be perpendicular unit vectors in ${\frak{su}}(2)$.  Then $P$ and $Q$ (as defined in my first comment) are distinct $S^1$-subgroups and their union generates all of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$.  It follows that $S_{A,B}$, which is easily seen to be a codimension-$2$ subset of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, cannot be a subgroup (though it does contain $P$ and $Q$).  Instead, it is a $1$-parameter family of cosets of an $S^1$-subgroup.

Comment: I understand your example. However, you are assuming that $P$ and $Q$ are maximal in the sense you described above. It is this step I'm failing to complete the details of. Why should we expect only the stabiliser subgroups of $A,B$ to leave the inner product unchanged?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to login in the chat discussion, so I'm continuing here:  I didn't *assume* that $P$ and $Q$ are maximal, I wrote that I thought it was likely.  In the particular case $n=2$ above, $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, which is $3$-dimensional, doesn't have any $2$-dimensional subgroups, so $P$ and $Q$ (which are $1$-dimensional) have maximal dimension by default.  Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: I mean that we are assuming it if the $SU(2)$ example is to represent the general case. The fact that $P,Q$ are maximal in this case is clear as you point out. In the $SU(4)$ case it is far less clear to me that they will be maximal but I expect that's because I lack the intuition that lead you to think they are in the first place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really an extended comment, but, because it's too long to put into a comment box and because it may help answer some of the OP's questions, I'm putting it here.

If one endows $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ with its usual bi-invariant measure $\mathrm{d}\mu$ normalized to have total volume $1$ (aka Haar measure), then one knows that, for any $B\in{\frak{su}}(n)$,
$$
\int_{U\in\mathrm{SU}(n)} \mathrm{Ad}_U(B)\ \mathrm{d}\mu = 0.
$$
(The integral has to be an element of ${\frak{su}}(n)$ that is $\mathrm{Ad}$-invariant, so it must be zero.)

This implies that, for any $A,B\in {\frak{su}}(n)$ the average value of the function $f:\mathrm{SU}(n)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(U) = K\bigl(A,\mathrm{Ad}_U(B)\bigr)$ over $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ is also zero.  Now, because the linear span of the $\mathrm{Ad}$-orbit of $B$ must be an $\mathrm{Ad}$-invariant subspace, it is either the zero subspace or all of ${\frak{su}}(n)$, so the only way that $f$ could vanish identically would be for either $A$ or $B$ to be zero.

In particular, it follows that, when $A$ and $B$ are both nonzero, the subset $S_{A,B} = f^{-1}(0)\subset \mathrm{SU}(n)$ divides its complement in $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ into two nonempty open sets and hence, since it is defined algebraically, it must be, at most places, a smooth hypersurface, i.e., it must have codimension $1$, at least where it is smooth.  (Because $f$ is real-analytic and $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ is connected, its zero locus cannot contain any nonempty open set.)

Now, there are no subgroups of $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ that have codimension $1$, so $S_{A,B}$ cannot ever be a subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ when both $A$ and $B$ are nonzero.

Of course, when $K(A,B)=0$, as I already mentioned, $S_{A,B}$ can contain subgroups, in particular, the subgroups $P$ and $Q$, which are the $\mathrm{Ad}$-stabilizers of $A$ and $B$, respectively.  Most of the time, though, these will be maximal subgroups of $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ that lie in $S_{A,B}$ because, generically, $P$ and $Q$ will be maximal tori, and hence there will only be a finite number of connected Lie subgroups that lie between, say $P$ and $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ itself.  When $B$ is generically chosen with respect to $A$, none of these properly sandwiched subgroups will lie in $S_{A,B}$, so $P$ will be maximal.  A similar argument applies to $Q$.

Comment: Thanks, a great answer as usual. Am I correct in saying that the Lie algebra of $P$ will simply by all the things that commute with $P$ in $\mathfrak{su}(n)$?. I'm trying to understand what else will be in $S_{A,B}$ in the case $K(A,B)=0$ other than $P \cup Q$.

Comment: @Benjamin:  The Lie algebra of $P$ will be all the things that commute with $A$ in ${\frak{su}}(n)$.  It's hard to say what else will be in $S_{A,B}$ since $S_{A,B}$ is of codimension $1$ in $\mathrm{SU}(n)$.  It will surely be larger than $P\cup Q$.

Comment: I meant commute with $A$. Assuming $A,B$ are regular elements, dim $P,Q$ will be $n$. As $S_{A,B}$ is co-dimension $1$ it's dim will (only in places where this makes sense, I'm not exactly sure how to make the precise) be $n^2 - 2$ right? So $P \cup Q$ is far from being the whole set $S_{A,B}$ it seems.

Comment: @Benjamin:  Actually, for regular elements, the dimension of $P$ and $Q$ will be $n{-}1$.  As long as $[A,B]\not=0$, the set $S_{A,B}$ will be smooth at the identity and its tangent space there will be the hyperplane in ${\frak{su}}(n)$ perpendicular to $[A,B]$.

Comment: Ok, the -1 is because $A$ is also traceless, I see. Thanks for your input, that issue is now much clearer.

Comment: I guess that $\log$ of $S_{A,B}$ will not be a vector subspace of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ but this seems tricky. It's very unclear to me which subsets of $SU(n)$ have the property that their $\log$ is a vector subspace of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$.

Comment: @Benjamin:  Correct.  For example, when $n=2$, $S_{A,B}$ is a torus embedded in $\mathrm{SU}(2)\simeq S^3$, while the exponentials of linear subspaces of ${\frak{su}}(2)\simeq\mathbb{R}^3$ are either great circles or spheres in $\mathrm{SU}(2)\simeq S^3$.  As for characterizing the preimage of $S_{A,B}$ under the exponential map in general, this is probably going to be somewhat messy.

Comment: So now my only point of confusion which remains is why $S_{A,B}$ is co-dim 2 in the case of $SU(2)$ (with $A,B$ orthogonal) as you say above but is co-dim 1 in general. The only case I'm actually interested in is the case where they are orthogonal so if this is the cause then that would be interesting.

Comment: Actually, isn't is always co dim 1? Any torus in $SU(2)$ would be?

Comment: Yes, co-dim 1 is correct for $S_{A,B}$.  I don't know why you were thinking co-dim 2; nothing I wrote would have suggested that.

Comment: It's very likely that I missed something, however you said "it follows that $S_{A,B}$, which is easily seen to be a codimension-2 subset.." in a comment on the original post. I may be confused. It is clear that in the $SU(2)$ case $P$ and $Q$ are both co dim 2.

Comment: @Benjamin:  Oh, sorry. That's was a typo; it should have been 'codimension-$1$'.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all you help! Hopefully this is related to quantum control somehow! We'll see....

Comment: So, it seems that for $SU(2)$ with $K(A,B)=0$ the product $PQ$ (which is a torus as you pointed out) is the whole of $S_{A,B}$. However $PQ$ in general will have dimension $2n+2$ (if $A,B$ both regular) so it will not be codim $1$. I'm failing to understand what else could be in $S_{A,B}$, can even a single example be found?